# Jquery slideder effects

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to add Fade-In Fade-out effects to the homepage of this [page](http://www.simco2.siteprogression.com) but it doesn't seem to take effect, it rather stops working. I'd like only the fade effect.

The function code is as shown below

```
script>
        $(function(){
            $('#slides').slides({
                fadeOut: true,
                preload: true,
                preloadImage: 'img/loading.gif',
                play: 5000,
                pause: 4000,
                hoverPause: true,
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and the HTML is below

```
<div id="slides">
        <div class="slides_container">
                    <a href="#" target="" ><img src="images/wire2.jpg"width="570" height="270" alt="Slide 1"></a>
                    <a href="#" title="" ><img src="images/wire1.jpg"width="570" height="270" alt="Slide 1"></a>
                    <a href="#" title="" ><img src="images/wire3.jpg"width="570" height="270" alt="Slide 1"></a>
                    <a href="#" title="" ><img src="images/wire4.jpg"width="570" height="270" alt="Slide 1"></a>
                    <a href="#" title="" ><img src="images/wire5.jpg"width="570" height="270" alt="Slide 1"></a>
                    <a href="#" title=""><img src="images/wire6.jpg"width="570" height="270" alt="Slide 1"></a>
                    <a href="#" title=""><img src="images/wire7.jpg"width="570" height="270" alt="Slide 1"></a>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Try removing the comma after `hoverPause:true`.

Comment: try using `$('.slides_container').slides({` and also delete the comma like @user1090389 said.

Comment: Try this, should be helpful: http://jsfiddle.net/sYhQC/ cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the options slide has:

```
preload: !1,  
preloadImage: "/img/loading.gif",  
container: "slides_container",  
generateNextPrev: !1,  
next: "next",  
prev: "prev",  
pagination: !0,  
generatePagination: !0,  
prependPagination: !1,  
paginationClass: "pagination",  
currentClass: "current",  
fadeSpeed: 350,  
fadeEasing: "",  
slideSpeed: 350,  
slideEasing: "",  
start: 1,  
effect: "slide",  
crossfade: !1,  
randomize: !1,  
play: 0,  
pause: 0,  
hoverPause: !1,  
autoHeight: !1,  
autoHeightSpeed: 350,  
bigTarget: !1,  
animationStart: function () {},  
animationComplete: function () {},  
slidesLoaded: function () {}
```

I don't think slide by it self has fade in and out effect.
Here is the website: http://slidesjs.com/